# how to push a value to an array with a ternary operator?

Tags: ruby

the array is returning a boolean value instead of the value assigned by the ternary operator

and the code...

```
arr = []
arr <<  true == false ? 'a' : 'b'
# Expecting, the output of arr to be ['b']. But instead, I was getting [true]
```

Why is this behavior?

and to get the right value I have to do this.

```
arr << if true == false
         'a'
       else
         'b'
       end  

# and also, = also works fine
arr =  true == false ? 'a' : 'b' # arr has 'b'
```

and why the behavior is different when using the ternary operator?

Comment: We all know the outcome of `true == false`. You could simply replace it by `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you all for helping, I like the solution by iGian i.e. without parenthesis.

```
arr <<= true == false ? 'a' : 'b'
```

Comment: This answer will be more useful to future readers if you explain *why* it works. Practically speaking what's the difference between `<<` and `<<=`?

Comment: If you already have a working solution, why do you use the conditional operator in the first place? You should, in general, prefer the conditional expression over the conditional operator, since the conditional operator has some non-intuitive precedence, as you just discovered. You already posted a solution with the conditional expression, and that one just works: `arr << if true == false then 'a' else 'b' end`

Comment: Hey Jorg, I was curious about why the conditional expression doesn't work and wanted to learn from experts.

Answer (score 16):

It is due to [Ruby's operator precedence](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/doc/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html). Operator `<<` has greater precedence than the ternary operator. Your example can be solved by modifying the code as below:

```
arr = []
arr << (true == false ? 'a' : 'b')
```

Comment: Alternatively `arr.push(true == false ? 'a' : 'b')`

Comment: Maybe it's a hack, but this also works: `arr  <<= true == false ? 'a' : 'b'`

Comment: Thank you iGian, this is the answer I'm looking for